# Sharepoint 2010 DocumentSets - How to Manage Programatically?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-set

I am new to Sharepoint 2010 but not new to .Net programming.

Here is my situation:

I have a large set of files to be uploaded into Sharepoint 2010 with metadata. I have decided to write a C# class library to handle the document sets programatically. I have to use Document sets. I am able to successfully create a document set. Now I am stuck with the following questions:

- How do I check if a document set already exists?
- How do I remove a document set?

Here is my code to create the document set:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(spURL))
            {
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPList docs = web.Lists["Documents"];
                        if (docs != null)
                        {

                            SPContentType docSetCT = docs.ContentTypes["Document Set"];

                            if (docSetCT != null)
                            {
                                Hashtable docsetProps = new Hashtable();
                                docsetProps.Add("New Docset", "New Docset");

                                DocumentSet docSet = DocumentSet.Create(docs.RootFolder, documentSetName, docSetCT.Id, docsetProps, true);

                                docs.Update();

                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 4):

The list of helper methods for working with Document Sets:

How do I check if a document set already exists?

```
private static bool IsDocumentSetExist(SPList list,string docSetName)
    {
        var folderUrl = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, docSetName);
        var folder = list.ParentWeb.GetFolder(folderUrl);
        return folder.Exists;
    }
```

Usage:

```
var docSetExists = IsDocumentSetExist(docs, "New Docset");
```

How do I remove a document set?

```
 private static void DeleteDocumentSet(DocumentSet docSet)
    {
        docSet.Folder.Delete();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this one worked perfect. I figured out by myself but there was performance problem with that, this one is clean.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.